# wp_list_pages get the hole hierarchy for current page

Tags: pages, hierarchical, wp-list-pages

Having for example the following page hierarchy

```
Page1
 - SubPage1_1
 - SubPage1_2
 -- SubSubPage1_2_1

Page2
 - SubPage2_1
 - SubPage2_2
 -- SubSubPage2_2_1
```

and requesting for example `SubSubPage1_2_1` how can I get with `wp_list_pages` the hole hierarchy? The expected result

```
Page1
     - SubPage1_1
     - SubPage1_2
     -- SubSubPage1_2_1
```

I have been trying the following

```
global $post;

if(!$post->post_parent){
    // will display the subpages of this top level page
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
}
else{

    if($post->ancestors) {
        // now you can get the the top ID of this page
        // wp is putting the ids DESC, thats why the top level ID is the last one

        $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".implode($ancestors, ',')."&echo=0");
    }
}
```

but in my case does not output the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```php
if ( ! $post->post_parent ) {
    $pages = get_pages( 'child_of=' . $post->ID );
    $pages = $pages ? wp_list_pluck( $pages, 'ID' ) : '';
    $includes = $post->ID . ( $pages ? ',' . implode( ',', $pages ) : '' );
    $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&include=' . $includes . '&echo=0' );
} else {
    $pages = get_post_ancestors( $post );
    $includes = $post->ID . ',' . implode( ',', $pages );
    $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&include=' . $includes . '&echo=0' );
}
echo $children ? "<ul>$children</ul>" : '';
```

I.e. Use the `include` parameter.

For top-level pages (`post_parent` is `0`), `$children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );` works as well, but doesn't include the parent's markup (`LI`) itself unless you manually add it. And I prefer of having the markup/`LI` be generated by `wp_list_pages()`.